# Displaying a Character in incremental using simple Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to display '#' symbol result in the below format using a Select Statement in SQL query by taking a number as parameter.

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= 10)
BEGIN
    PRINT '#'
    SET @Counter = @Counter +1
    
END
```

Result to be displayed as:

```
#
##
###
####
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? SQL is a set based language, so the last thing you should be doing is looping. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a system table `spt_values` with running numbers.

As many already said there is no need for any loops.

**SQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT number
    , REPLICATE('#', number) AS Result
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+------------+
| number |   Result   |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | #          |
|      2 | ##         |
|      3 | ###        |
|      4 | ####       |
|      5 | #####      |
|      6 | ######     |
|      7 | #######    |
|      8 | ########   |
|      9 | #########  |
|     10 | ########## |
+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InCounter TINYINT;
SET @InCounter=1;
WHILE(@InCounter<=10)
BEGIN
   PRINT REPLICATE('#',@INCOUNTER);
   SET @InCounter=@InCounter+1;
END
```

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you so much